# Linux remove all empty lines and corresponding line above it

Tags: linux, bash, sed, grep, tac

I am trying to delete all empty lines, including spaces or tabs, and the line right above the empty line.

I have successfully used grep to get the empty line and the line above it, using `grep -B 1 -e '^[[:space:]]*$' filename` . I have tried adding the -v flag to remove the match from my file. However, no change is made.

My file looks like this

```
            967 
      
              7
7836  783  273
              6
```

The output should be

```
              7
7836  783  273
              6
```

I have also tried to use `tac filename | sed '/^$/I,+1 d' | tac'`, but I believe this does not work because my empty line might contain spaces or tabs. How could I achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: What is the expected output if there are consecutive blank lines?

Comment: You might be able to `diff` the output of your `grep` and your file. Something like `diff --changed-group-format='%<' --unchanged-group-format='' src.txt <(grep -B 1 -e '^[[:space:]]*$' src.txt)`

Comment: 967 didn't become seven. The desired output is correct, based on what he is requesting. But it can be put in simpler words which would be easier to translate into code. "Remove lines with content that are followed by 'empty' lines with potential tabs or spaces. Including the 'empty' lines."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if Your empty lines could contain spaces then
`tac <fileName> | sed -E '/^\s*$/,+1 d' | tac`

Answer (score 1):

With [perl](/questions/tagged/perl):

In slurp mode: `-0777` read the whole file in memory:

```
$ perl -0777 -pe 's/.*\n\s*\n//g' file
```

with `Perl` => 5.36:

```
$  perl -gpe 's/.*\n\s*\n//g' file
```

With `GNU` `sed`:

```
sed -rz 's/[^\n]*\n\s*\n//g' file
```

##### Output

```
              7
7836  783  273
              6
```

Comment: `sed -rz 's/[^\n]*\n\s*\n//g' file`

Comment: Added to the list

Comment: Seems like you want this:  The g is what I mentioned earlier: `perl -0777 -pe 's/.*\n\s*\n//g'`

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'N;/\n\s*$/d;/^\s*\n/!P;D' file
```

Open a two line window.

If the second line of the window is empty, delete both lines.

If the first line of the window is empty, don't print it.

Otherwise, print then delete the first line and repeat.

Comment: I failed to do this with hold space.  Nice to see it can be done entirely with pattern space.